# upload file to server and make a pointer to it using xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, file-upload

My web application allow the web admin to upload file to the server and name this file "input for file name and input for the file". On the files page the user can click the file name and get the file uploaded by the admin. My question is how I can upload a file and get the entered name using XML.  I know how to upload file to the server using JSP/servlet I just need to link the file name with the file uploaded to the server

thank you

Comment: What do you mean about XML? Maybe some code would make this clearer.

Comment: I mean XML file so I have tag for the <name> and tag for the uploaded <file>. So when the admin add file a new content will added to the XML file. Example <name> Data One </name><file> file path on the server .. </file><name> Data Two</name><file> file path on the server .. </file>

Comment: Use a db not a flat XML file. If 2 users upload a file at the same time, and you try to write to the same flat XML file, one might fail to update the XML due to sharing violation.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. but Actually I only have one admin who can add file.

Answer (score 1):

When saving the file in your server, you will create a new File. You have the option to set the name here.

```
String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
File baseDir = new File("/path/to/save/the/files/");
File file = new File(baseDir, fileName);
//here you receive the InputStream that holds the data from the file uploaded
//since I don't know how you're retrieving it, I'll put three dots
InputStream inputStream = ...
//save the file in disk...
```

Comment: Thank you :). you solved the name problem but now when I want to retrieve the uploaded files to be displayed to the users so they can download the file after clicking the name. Is it possible to retrieve all files names stored in specific folder on the server ?

Comment: @reem.abd you should zip the files, then stream the zip file for download.

Comment: no I mean when I have file_1 and file_2 on the server, I need to display to the user - file_1 \n -file_2 so that when he click he can get the files. I know how to implemented using DB but I don't want to use DB. thank you

Comment: So you mean how to read the folder to display the files to user?

Comment: Exactly, How I can display the added folders in the server to the users ?